# Thunderbird: forward emails to same recipient

Tags: email, thunderbird, forwarding

I have several emails with large attachments that I want to forward to a particular email address. I can't forward these emails as attachments, because then the resulting email would be too large. How can I forward all the emails without having to send them manually one at a time?

Comment: I'd like to avoid have the sender need to download all the attachments

Answer (score 2):

Just found this and was playing with the same problem - wanted to forward 90 emails to a single email address one by one.
Looked at extensions but none run with 78
Looked at moving to a gmail folder and use chrome extensions to forward but all required payment.

So how to do it?

1. Copy all the required emails to a new single folder - then select that new folder
2. Add a new filter to forward to the required email address
3. Make the filter manual run only
4. Run the filter on the selected folder

Done..

I caveat . I found that AVG was limiting fast outgoing emails  so disabled it for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Are both email accounts available on the same Thunderbird instance? If so, you can simply move the email to the appropriate folder on the other account. This works with incoming message filters.

If that is not possible, the standard way of doing it would be to apply a filter on the **server** rather than the client. Of course, that doesn't involve Thunderbird and would require some access to the server unless the server is running IMAP with Sieve filtering installed. Update your question if needed and I'll expand this part of the answer.

Basically, if you cannot forward the email, your options are very limited. There is, though, one other possibility. Thunderbird now allows you to use external storage for attachments. You can use Box.net, Ubuntu One and YouSendIt to store attachments and get Thunderbird to send just a link.

Comment: No, only one of the accounts is mine. Also I don't have access to the server... both are GMail accounts.

About the external storage thing, I think thunderbird's attachment extraction extension wouldn't work with it, so I think it is not a viable solution.

Comment: Then I think you are asking for the impossible as there are no real options left. If you cannot forward the emails and you can't bring both accounts to the same client then you have to offload the attachments to external storage. Not sure what else I can say really. Sorry.

Comment: The emails can be forwarded... but one at a time, manually. I can't bring both accounts to the same client because the other account isn't mine, and its owner wouldn't give me access to his email for this. I guess I'll have to try the external storage thing then. Thanks.